# Strange behaviour of Javascript `new` from `function`

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've just run into something that really surprises me. Consider the following four functions:

```
function A() {
 this.q = 1;
}

function B() {
 this.q = 1;
 return this;
}

function C() {
 this.q = 1;
 return 42;
}

function D() {
 this.q = 1;
 return {};
}
```

and let's create objects (via `new`) from all of them:

```
console.log('a', new A());
console.log('b', new B());
console.log('c', new C());
console.log('d', new D());
```

This is the output:

```
a A { q: 1 }
b B { q: 1 }
c C { q: 1 }
d {}
```

First three seem to indicate that it doesn't matter what the function returns, that JS only cares about what each function does with `this` (which was my previous believe, btw). But the last one contradicts that.

So, what's happening here? My revised rule would be "if the function returns an `Object`, we keep that. Otherwise, we keep `this`". But I feel quite unsure about it.

Comment: read point 4 of [this description of the new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) *Returns this if the function doesn't return an object.* - so, you've nailed it with your revised rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the **new** operator it creates an object.

The return value is as expected. If in the return it is an object will return that object otherwise if the return it is a function will return that function.

```
function A(){
    this.b = 3;
    return function(){return 4;};
}
function B(){
    this.b = 3;
    return { d:4};
}

console.log(typeof (new A())); //function
console.log(typeof (new B())); //object {d:4}
```

If any other value or non-existent in the return, **this** operator will take precedence returned as an object.

```
function C(){
    this.b = 3;
    return "78";
}
console.log(typeof (new C())); // object {b:3}
```

Comment: I'm selecting this as the accepted answers because it also includes the case where `typeof F` is `function` instead of `object`. @Lorand, please also include the [link from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) provided by @Jaromanda X.

Answer (score 3):

in JavaScript when you invoke a function without new like `test()` it just runs the function and it. returns whatever is being returned by the function

while when you invoke a function with new like `new test()` it expects the return statement to return an object else return `this` object.

so

```
function test() {
    this.q = 1
}

test(); // return undefined

new test(); // return {q:1}
```